# how to get email id from facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i can't get email id from all facebook users from facebook graph api. but when the facebook user  sets his email id privacy as only me,i can't get their email id from facebook graph api (php).

```
$fbuser_profile = $this->fbconnect->api("/$fbuser",array("access_token"=>$access_token,'scope' => 'email,read_stream'));

            $fbuser_pro = $this->fbconnect->api("/me?fields=email,gender",array("access_token"=>$access_token));
```

these two api calls get some users email id not all users.

Comment: this has been asked a lot already, you can never be 100% sure to get an email back. search through the countless stackoverflow threads about the issue.

Comment: is this nt possible to get email id from user through api?

Comment: it is, but you can not be sure to get it